# pptp tunnel stalling with qbittorrent

Tags: networking, vpn

Sometimes i like to have an extra layer of anonymity when downloading files from p2p networks using the torrent protocol.

I establish a pptp conection using Debian PPPD, have a look at the settings in my config file:

```
pty "pptp myvpnpptpserver.net --nolaunchpppd --debug"
name myusername
password mypassword
remotename PPTP
require-mppe-128
require-mschap-v2
refuse-eap
refuse-pap
refuse-chap
refuse-mschap
noauth
debug
persist
maxfail 0
defaultroute
replacedefaultroute
usepeerdns
```

I configure my torrent client (qbittorrent v3.1.8) to bind to interface ppp0

I start my VPN by issuing a "sudo pon myconfig", and check that the link is established with ifconfig. Everything works, i verify that my traffic is going through ppp0 by checking my IP using various websites, everything works.

I start up qbittorrent, check the execution log to see what qbittorrent reports as my external IP, and when everything checks out, i begin retrieval of my files.

**Here comes the problem. The download goes fine for a couple of minutes, then suddenly my connection stalls, or halts, and no further traffic gets through. I check if i am still connected, and sure enough, i am. However, no website, no ping, nothing gets through.**

I close my torrent program, reset the pptp connection, and everything works again.

Now, i know what you're thinking. Could it be the VPN provider? No, i tried this with several providers and some of my own servers, the same stalling occurs. I might point out that when i use windows, and the client provided by my VPN provider, this issue is nonexistent.

This seems to be a specific issue with my configuration, unfortunately i have run out of ideas where to troubleshoot the issue.

Here is what i have tried:

- Reducing the number of concurrent connections in qbittorrent
- Reducing the download/upload speed
- Reducing the number of half-open connections
- setting up proper port-forwarding

There's no errors of anything related in the logs either. It seems the connection just chokes up and goes unresponsive, interestingly enough, if you just wait long enough, it fixes itself after 10 minutes or so. Could it be related to any timeout settings i wonder?

Where do i go from here? I'm out of ideas, other than to manually reset my connection every few minutes until my download is completed.